# How to retrieve numRows, resultSize from query in BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Is it possible to retrieve the total number of rows that a query has returned without downloading all the results? For example, here is what I'm currently doing:

```
client = bigquery.Client()
res = client.query("SELECT funding_round_type FROM `investments`")
results = res.result()

>>> results.num_results
0
>>> records = [_ for _ in results]
>>> results.num_results
168647
```

In other words, without downloading the results, I cannot get the `numResults`. Is there another way to get the total number of results / number of MB in the resultant query set without having to download all the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Result of any query is stored in so called anonymous table. You can retrieve the reference to this table using [jobs.get API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get). and then you can use [tables.get API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/get) to retrieve info about that table  - rows and size in particular. For example, in python:

```
>>> table = client.get_table(res.destination)
>>> print (table.num_rows, table.num_bytes)
168647 1451831
```

Comment: exactly, glad you added py version of it :o)